# How to set window height and width when using iFrame in FancyBox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I  use fancy box to open up some set `width` / `height` `HTML` pages without scroll bars but I'm unsure how to do this in the `fancy box j-query` function.

I have all the relevant scripts and `Fancy box` is working fine, but if I specify `iframe` it opens up at a small default size.

Do I alter this script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".iframe").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

I want to open the HTML page from clicking on an image...

```
<div class="project">
<a class="iframe" href="#"><img src="images/portfolio/blank-image.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="100"></a>
</div>
```

Could anyone suggest how I would open up a window that is `800px width by 500px height` without scroll bars (the `HTML` document will be created to fit those exact dimensions) and perhaps include some transitions like elastic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify fancybox options like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $("a.iframe").fancybox({
                'width': 800,
                'height': 500,
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                'type': 'iframe'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Cheers BarryF - Apologies for late reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the width and height of a fancyBox with the following added to your fancyBox script:

```
width       : 800,
height      : 500
```

If you don't want scroll bars to be generated, you can add the following to your fancyBox script:

```
scrolling   : 'no'
```

Hope this helps!